# batch rename zip files based on contained file names

Tags: command-line, bash, perl, zip, batch-rename

I've got a directory with 15000 zip files. I'd like to rename all files which, when unzipped, contain a file of the form

```
YYYYMMDD_IPC.csv
```

where `YYYYMMDD` happens to be a date but for the purposes of this problem is any string of exactly 8 digits. Then, the zip file itself should be renamed to

```
YYYYMMDD_IPC.zip.
```

I have gotten as far as the following command line but I don't know how to capture the `YYYYMMDD` from the contained file to use in order to rename the zip files:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' | while read file; do unzip -l "$file" | grep -q -P '\d{8}_IPC.csv' && echo $file; done 2>&-
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -exec bash -c 'name=$(unzip -qql "$1"  '*_IPC.csv' | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{8}_IPC.csv' | head -n1); [ "$name" ] && mv "$1" "${name%csv}zip"' none {} ';'
```

#### How it works

This  command has the form:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -exec bash -c '...' none {} ';'
```

This searches for .zip file in the current directory and all subdirectories under it.  For each such file found the bash command in single quotes is executed.  The name of the file found is supplied at argument one, `$1`, to the bash command.  In our case, the bash command has two parts.  The first extracts the csv file name and saves it in bash variable `name`:

```
name=$(unzip -qql "$1"  '*_IPC.csv' | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{8}_IPC.csv' | head -n1)
```

The above uses *command substitution*: the command inside `$(...)` is run and its standard out is captured.  In this case, we assign it to the variable `name`.  The command `unzip -qql "$1"  '*_IPC.csv'` quietly extracts all file names from the zip file that match the glob `*_IPC.csv`.  We don't need to limit to the glob `*_IPC.csv` but, if the zip file has many files in it, this may speed things up.

The grep command, `rep -oE '[[:digit:]]{8}_IPC.csv'` further selects only those name that start with 8 digits.  The `head -n1` command selects the first such name found.  If there was only one such name, `head -n1` wouldn't be needed.  But, keeping `head` could speed things up because it causes the pipeline to terminate after the first match.

The second part tests that we succeeded in getting a non-empty `name` and, if so, renames the zip file:

```
[ "$name" ] && mv "$1" "${name%csv}zip"
```

The above uses *suffix removal* to change the csv file name to a zip file name.  `${name%csv}` returns `$name` after having removed the suffix `csv`.  `${name%csv}zip` adds a zip suffix.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Outstanding!  Thank you.